# How to auto update data on ionic list without refreshing the page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I created a page that contains ionic list and there was two buttons if clicking on that button it call a firebase api and it get updated. ones it updates, whole list get refresh. How to stop refresh of whole list.

[image]

```
 onLocationDataUpdate() {
    // Get current location
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(position => {
      this.location.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      this.location.lng = position.coords.longitude;

      // Get location data from Firebase
      this.connectivityServiceService.getLocations(
        this.locatingRange,
        this.location.lat,
        this.location.lng
      );

      // Bind data to Ionic list
      this.dataSetSubscription = this.connectivityServiceService.geoPointLocationUpdateNotify.subscribe(
        locations => {
          const locationData = this.connectivityServiceService.getGeoPointLocations();
          if (locationData.length > this.maxDataCount) {
            const tempLocationData = locationData.slice(0, this.maxDataCount);
            tempLocationData.forEach(item => {
              if (item.feed_back === undefined) {
                item = Object.assign(item, {
                  feed_back: { count: 0, positive: [], negative: [] }
                });
              }
            });
            this.geoPointLocationData = tempLocationData;
            this.loader.dismiss();
          } else {
            const tempLocationData = locationData;
            tempLocationData.forEach(item => {
              if (item.feed_back === undefined) {
                item = Object.assign(item, {
                  feed_back: { count: 0, positive: [], negative: [] }
                });
              }
            });
            this.geoPointLocationData = tempLocationData;
            this.loader.dismiss();
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you replacing the existing model or pushing to it?

Comment: Seems like I'm replacing. existing model

Comment: Then please try pushing the new data to the model. Hope it will solve the issue.

Comment: Yes its solve the issue. Thank you ! it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you have resolved this to your satisfaction but you did actually hit on something here.

By just pushing new data to the model you are going to see it update but under the hood it is recreating that whole list.

If the data gets long then this could give you performance issues. At this point you should look into `trackBy`.

It's a method of giving Angular a way to track each individual item in the list so that when it comes to updating it, Angular can figure out which ones actually need to be updated and only change them.

This seems like a [decent introduction to the topic](https://medium.com/simars/improve-ngfor-usability-and-performance-with-trackby-97f32ab92f1c).